# All my virtual host go to the same site?

Tags: virtualhost, apache2.4

I am having a problem with virtual host, all of them go to one site and I dont know why.

This is a typical vhost config for one of many domains:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

### SERVER ###
##############
ServerName domain.com
ServerAlias www.domain.com
ServerAdmin domains@domain.com
DocumentRoot /mnt/volume1/domain

### DIRECTORY ###
#################
<Directory /mnt/volume1/domain/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>

### LOGS ###
############
LogLevel info
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/domain.access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Apache Version is 2.4.6 -- Ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a virtual host for all the sites

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName domain1.com
  ServerAlias www.domain1.com
  ServerAdmin domains@domain1.com
  DocumentRoot /mnt/volume1/domain1

  ## Rest of the settings here for domain1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName domain2.com
  ServerAlias www.domain2.com
  ServerAdmin domains@domain2.com
  DocumentRoot /mnt/volume1/domain2

  ##rest of the settings here for domain2
</VirtualHost>
```

restart apache and you should have the domains pointing to the right directory...

You might have to to use the `sudo a2ensite domain1` command to enable the sites in

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available
```

that way you can set up seperate files for all your virtual hosts ... easier to manage... :)

apache2 allows you to make seperate sites... so check the

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default
```

if you don't have the sites enabled everything by defaults gets pointed to that 000-default virtual host

you have to make sure there is a link in

```
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
```

folder to the config files in

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available
```

folder... :)

Cheers...

Comment: All the sites have their own configs and are enabled. Still all goes to one domain.

Comment: I got it. I forgot to reload the config files with /etc/init.d/apache2 reload. After doing that then restarting apache2 with /etc/init.d/apache2 restart, it works.

Comment: cool glad you got it running ... :)